# Generating strongly biased random numbers for tests

Tags: random, lua, automated-tests, distribution

I want to run tests with randomized inputs and need to generate 'sensible' random
numbers, that is, numbers that match good enough to pass the tested function's
preconditions, but hopefully wreak havoc deeper inside its code.

`math.random()` (I'm using Lua) produces uniformly distributed random 
numbers. Scaling these up will give far more big numbers than small numbers, 
and there will be very few integers.

I would like to skew the random numbers (or generate new ones using the old
function as a randomness source) in a way that strongly favors 'simple' numbers,
but will still cover the whole range, i.e., extending up to positive/negative infinity
(or `±1e309` for `double`). This means:

- numbers up to, say, ten should be most common,
- integers should be more common than fractions,
- numbers ending in 0.5 should be the most common fractions,
- followed by 0.25 and 0.75; then 0.125,
- and so on.

A different description: Fix a base probability *x* such that probabilities
will sum to one and define the probability of a number *n* as *x<sup>k</sup>*
where *k* is the generation in which *n* is constructed as a surreal
number<sup>**1**</sup>. That assigns *x* to 0, *x<sup>2</sup>* to -1 and +1,
*x<sup>3</sup>* to -2, -1/2, +1/2 and +2, and so on. This
gives a nice description of something close to what I want (it skews a bit too
much), but is near-unusable for computing random numbers. The resulting
distribution is nowhere continuous (it's fractal!), I'm not sure how to
determine the base probability `x` (I think for infinite precision it would be
zero), and computing numbers based on this by iteration is awfully
slow (spending near-infinite time to construct large numbers).

Does anyone know of a simple approximation that, given a uniformly distributed
randomness source, produces random numbers very roughly distributed as
described above?

I would like to run thousands of randomized tests, quantity/speed is more
important than quality. Still, better numbers mean less inputs get rejected.

Lua has a JIT, so performance is usually not much of an issue. However, jumps based
on randomness will break every prediction, and many calls to `math.random()`
will be slow, too. This means a closed formula will be better than an
iterative or recursive one.

---

<sup>1</sup> Wikipedia has an [article on surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number), with
a [nice picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Surreal_number_tree.svg). A surreal number is a pair of two surreal
numbers, i.e. `x := {n|m}`, and its value is the number in the middle of the
pair, i.e. (for finite numbers) `{n|m} = (n+m)/2` (as rational). If one side
of the pair is empty, that's interpreted as increment (or decrement, if right
is empty) by one. If both sides are empty, that's zero. Initially, there are
no numbers, so the only number one can build is `0 := { | }`. In generation
two one can build numbers `{0| } =: 1` and `{ |0} =: -1`, in three we get
`{1| } =: 2`, `{|1} =: -2`, `{0|1} =: 1/2` and `{-1|0} =: -1/2` (plus some
more complex representations of known numbers, e.g. `{-1|1} ? 0`). Note that
e.g. `1/3` is never generated by finite numbers because it is an infinite
fraction – the same goes for floats, `1/3` is never represented exactly.

Comment: One thing to note is that floating-point numbers are *not* uniformly distributed in their range.

Answer (score 1):

How's this for an algorithm?

1. Generate a random float in (0, 1) with a library function
2. Generate a random integral roundoff point according to a desired probability density function (e.g. 0 with probability 0.5, 1 with probability 0.25, 2 with probability 0.125, ...).
3. 'Round' the float by that roundoff point (e.g. `floor((float_val << roundoff)+0.5)`)
4. Generate a random integral exponent according to another PDF (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3 with probability 0.1 each, and decreasing thereafter)
5. Multiply the rounded float by 2<sup>exponent</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

For a surreal-like decimal expansion, you need a random binary number.
*Even* bits tell you whether to stop or continue, *odd* bits tell you whether to go right or left on the tree:

```
> 0... => 0.0 [50%] Stop
> 100... => -0.5 [<12.5%] Go, Left, Stop
> 110... => 0.5 [<12.5%] Go, Right, Stop
> 11100... => 0.25 [<3.125%] Go, Right, Go, Left, Stop
> 11110... => 0.75 [<3.125%] Go, Right, Go, Right, Stop
> 1110100... => 0.125
> 1110110... => 0.375
> 1111100... => 0.625
> 1111110... => 0.875
```

One way to quickly generate a random binary number is by looking at the decimal digits in math.random() and replace 0-4 with '1' and 5-9 with '1':

- 0.8430419054348022
  becomes
  1000001010001011
  which becomes `-0.5`
- 0.5513009827118367
  becomes
  1100001101001011
  which becomes `0.25`
  etc

Haven't done much lua programming, but in Javascript you can do:

```
Math.random().toString().substring(2).split("").map(
    function(digit) { return digit >= "5" ? 1 : 0 }
);
```

or true binary expansion:

```
Math.random().toString(2).substring(2)
```

Not sure which is more genuinely "random" -- you'll need to test it.

You *could* generate surreal numbers in this way, but most of the results will be decimals in the form a/2^b, with relatively few integers. On Day 3, only 2 integers are produced (-3 and 3) vs. 6 decimals, on Day 4 it is 2 vs. 14, and on Day n it is 2 vs (2^n-2).

If you add two uniform random numbers from `math.random()`, you get a new distribution which has a "triangle" like distribution (linearly decreasing from the center). Adding 3 or more will get a more 'bell curve' like distribution centered around 0:

```
math.random() + math.random() + math.random()  - 1.5
```

Dividing by a random number will get a truly wild number:

```
A/(math.random()+1e-300)
```

This will return an results between A and (*theoretically*) A*1e+300,
though my tests show that 50% of the time the results are between A and 2*A
and about 75% of the time between A and 4*A.

Putting them together, we get:

```
round(6*(math.random()+math.random()+math.random() - 1.5)/(math.random()+1e-300))
```

This has over 70% of the number returned between -9 and 9 with a few big numbers popping up rarely.

Note that the average and sum of this distribution will tend to diverge towards a large negative or positive number, because the more times you run it, the more likely it is for a small number in the denominator to cause the number to "blow up" to a large number such as 147,967 or -194,137.

See [gist](https://gist.github.com/3957208) for sample code.

[Josh](http://about.me/joshuaweinstein)

Answer (score 0):

You can immediately calculate the nth born surreal number.

Example, the 1000th Surreal number is:

1. convert to binary:

   1000 dec = 1111101000 bin
2. 1's become pluses and 0's minuses:

   1111101000

   +++++-+---
3. The first '1' bit is 0 value, the next set of similar numbers is +1 (for 1's) or -1 (for 0's), then the value is 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc for each subsequent bit.

   1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0

   + + + + + - + - - -

   0 1 1 1 1 h h h h h

   +0+1+1+1+1-1/2+1/4-1/8-1/16-1/32

   = 3+17/32

   = 113/32

   = 3.53125

The binary length in bits of this representation is equal to the day on which that number was born.

Left and right numbers of a surreal number are the binary representation with its tail stripped back to the last 0 or 1 respectively.

Surreal numbers have an even distribution between -1 and 1 where half of the numbers created to a particular day will exist. 1/4 of the numbers exists evenly distributed between -2 to -1 and 1 to 2 and so on. The max range will be negative to positive integers matching the number of days you provide. The numbers go to infinity slowly because each day only adds one to the negative and positive ranges and days contain twice as many numbers as the last.

Edit:

A good name for this bit representation is "sinary"

Negative numbers are transpositions. ex:

```
100010101001101s -> negative number (always start 10...)

111101010110010s -> positive number (always start 01...)
```

and we notice that all bits flip accept the first one which is a transposition.

Nan is => 0s (since all other numbers start with 1), which makes it ideal for representation in bit registers in a computer since leading zeros are required (we don't make ternary computer anymore... too bad)

All Conway surreal algebra can be done on these number without needing to convert to binary or decimal.

The sinary format can be seem as a one plus a simple one's counter with a 2's complement decimal representation attached.

Here is an incomplete report on finary (similar to sinary): https://github.com/peawormsworth/tools/blob/master/finary/Fine%20binary.ipynb